# C++ API design shared_ptr and calling into functions

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, api-design

I have similar C++ code to this:

```
struct Data { /* ... */ }
int SomeFunction1(const Data& data) { return 0; }
int SomeFunction2(std::shared_ptr<Data>& data) { return 0; } // this is non-const though
int SomeFunction3(const Data* data) { return 0; } // possibility of receiving nullptr

int main()
{
  auto data = std::make_shared<Data>(); /* initialization somehow */;
  return SomeFunction1(*data.get()); // (1) call get and dereference the pointer
  return SomeFunction2(data); // (2) create an API that accepts the shared pointer
  return SomeFunction3(data.get()) // (3) create an API that accepts raw pointers
}
```

Please, ignore for the sake of simplicity that I can use a `unique_ptr` in this specific example.

To me, (1) seems preferable, but I am wondering whether the code at the caller `*data.get()` is common or rather some kind of design smell?

Comment: ¿Why not write `*data` instead of `*data.get()`? Also note that (2) has a possibility of receiving nullptr as well

Comment: You could replace `*data.get()` with `*data`.

Comment: That depends on what `SomeFunction` wants to do with the data?  If it is meant as read-only and always valid, then `SomeFunction1` seems the best.

Comment: Thanks, only using *data without the get is the part that I missed.

Comment: It depends on the situation. If `SomeFunction` takes the argument, does a computation, and returns then I agree that (1) is best - since in this case the `shared_ptr` is an irrelevant implementation detail. But if `SomeFunction` in any way keeps the argument (or parts of the argument) around after it returns, then (2) is the easy way to deal with lifetime issues.

Comment: Agree on recommendation of (1) so far – if a null pointer is a valid argument as well (and you do *not* want to change the smart pointer passed to), then I'd go with (3), as this is more flexible (you can use the same function then for *any* smart pointer), (2) only if you need to re-assign the smart pointer.

Comment: passing a smart pointer somewhere is about transfer of ownership. `SomeFunction2` has no buisness with ownership of the `Data`. It does something then returns. Only when a function keeps a reference (which is actually rather rare for a free function) you need to consider ownership

Comment: the important details are left out. In face of that, there is no obvious reason to dynamically allocate `Data` in the first place.

Comment: About transferring ownership: If this indeed needs to be done then we cannot accept the smart pointer by reference, but need to accept by value (copy it) instead!

Comment: There's a [gotw](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/30/gotw-91-smart-pointer-parameters/) by Herb Sutter on the matter, by the way, definitely worth reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `shared.get()` is not usually an indicator that everything is going well. However, in your example, you don't need `get()` because `std::shared_ptr` overloads `operator*`, so you can simply say `SomeFunction1(*data)`.

This is preferably if the function does not take shared ownership of the object, which seems to be the case. Otherwise you would have to copy the `std::shared_ptr` object.